# PHP Update MySQL Column is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have php page that you can type in a number and then click the submit button and it should update the column in the table.
The problem I have is that it isn't updating the value but just leaving an empty field.

Something seems to be wrong with this line.

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE sip SET callerid = '$new' WHERE name = $trial");
```

If I just change the $new to a number it works fine. If I echo $new I get a number. Also the $trial bit works fine.

The full code I have is below.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
<link href="/../site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<? include("../header.php") ?>  
<div id="main">


<?php
session_start();
$trial = $_SESSION['random'];
echo "Random: ".$trial;

if(empty($_SESSION['random'])) {
header("Location:/site/home.php");
}

   echo "<br />";
?>

    <form action="customer_details.php" method="post">
    Number: <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="4" min="1000" max="9999" />
     <br /><br />
    <input type="Submit" />

</form>


<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test' , $link) or die("Unable to select database: asterisk" . mysql_error());


if(isset($_POST['phone']))
{

$phone = $_POST['phone'];



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where number = '$phone'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{

$data = $row['callerid'];
}

echo $phone;

if($phone = $data)
{

print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'alert("Number is already in database")'; 
print '</script>';

}
else {
$new = $phone;
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE sip SET callerid = '$new' WHERE name = $trial");

if(! $update )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'alert("New Data added");'; 
print 'window.location.href = "../home.php";';
print '</script>';
}

}

}
?>

<? include("../footer.php") ?> 
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Agreed with @RUJordan, any errors?

Comment: No I haven't got any errors. Might try check the logs but don't think that will help.
Not worried about SQL injection as nothing is that important on it.

Comment: have you try to use mysqli?

Comment: this bit here "if ($phone = $data) {" is resetting the value of phone. you need to use ==

Comment: did you check $trial has the value

Comment: Thanks @bumperbox that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$phone` to `$data` instead of comparing their values.

```
if($phone = $data)
{

print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'alert("Number is already in database")'; 
print '</script>';

}
```

Change `$phone = $data` to `$phone == $data`.  Right now, this condition block will always execute and the `else` (where your update is set to run) will not.

**Side note:** If the values of either of the variables contains single quotes and you're using single quotes to set the value in the query (as you should), than it's not only a question of being an injection vulnerability but it just won't update correctly.

Comment: I changed to == and it fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotes like this:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE sip SET callerid = '$new' WHERE name = '$trial'");
```

Comment: I have tried that single quotes around $trial and makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quotes for variables which are not integers and no need to use single quotes for integers.

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE sip SET callerid ='".$new."' WHERE name ='".$trial."'");
```

and change this line

```
if($phone = $data)  // here you are assigning the value of $data to $phone
```

to

```
if($phone == $data) // you have to compare it using ==
```

Comment: If I remove the single quotes around $new. I receive the following error: Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE name = '200101'' at line 1

Comment: what are the datatypes of fields callerid and name?

Comment: callerid is varchar(80) and name is varchar(80)

Comment: try with my updated answer..let me know if you are getting any sql errors. You can echo the query like echo "update sip SET .....";exit; and execute the query in the database and check whether u r getting any errors.

Comment: I tried added the '". and page didn't load. But I did and echo of the mysql_query and it return UPDATE sip SET callerid =  WHERE 200101.

Comment: then u r not getting the value for $new in that line..check for it

Comment: If you check my code I have an echo $phone;. That shows the number fine. Now if I do that echo $phone in the else statement before the $new = $phone it doesn't show the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE sip SET callerid = '{$new}' WHERE name = '{$trial}'");